# How do implementations like Spring Cloud Sleuth are made?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, spring-cloud-sleuth

By adding Spring Cloud Sleuth as a dependency in my Spring Boot project the logging mask, like magic, changes.
The change that happens is the inclusion of the traceId, spanId and applicationName in the informations that are logged when I do `log.info(...)` and other logging commands.

How do Spring Cloud Sleuth does that? Is that a appender implementation? Do a programatically change happens in the log mask to be able to print it when Spring Boot auto-configuration is started?

Comment: Although Sleuth is complex and do a lot of thing, but from the angle of logging, it just put those data into MDC context and on startup replace the logging mask.